# Laravel showing only advertisements related to post

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel.

I want to display advertisements on each post contains same category_id.
I tried like below but I think this does not work.

Can you advise?

```
posts
 id 
 category_id
 title
 body


advertisements
 id
 category_id
 title
 body


$advertisements = DB::table('advertisements')
         ->join('posts', function ($join) {
             $join->on('advertisements.category_id', '=', 'posts.category_id')
               ->where('posts.category_id', '=', 'advertisements.category_id');
         })

         ->get();
```

Comment: The relationship type between the tables is one-to-one?

Comment: Might be One To Many? Each Post has more than one advertisement.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$ads = DB::table('advertisements')
->join('posts', 'posts.category_id', '=', 'advertisements.category_id')
->get();
```

But you actually want posts with corresponding ads, according to your title.

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')
->leftjoin('advertisements', 'advertisements.category_id', '=', 'posts.category_id')
->get();
```

If you want to use Eloquent and you have your relationships defined properly, you can do

```
$posts = Post::with('category.advertisements')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it. Anyway, what is ('category.advertisements')?

Comment: if you have relationships defined in your model properly, it will take `$post->category->advertisements` Because Post belongs to Category and Category has many Advertisements.

Answer (score 0):

For a One to Many relationship, try use Eloquent:

Post.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the advertisements for the post.
     */
    public function advertisements()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Advertisement');
    }
}
```

Advertisement.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Advertisement extends Model
{

}
```

Somewhere in the code use this

```
$posts = App\Post::all();

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    dd($post->advertisements)
}
```